# Java: using deriveFont does not change font size

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, size

I am loading a custom font (from ttf file) into my project, and using deriveFont(float f) to change the size. However, the size is not actually being set (stuck at 1). Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    try {
        Font mont =
                Font.createFont(
                        Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
                        new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/Montserrat-MediumItalic.ttf"))
                        .deriveFont(20f);
        ge.registerFont(mont);

        Arrays.stream(ge.getAllFonts())
                .filter(font -> font.getFontName().contains("Mont"))
                .forEach(font -> System.out.println(font.getFontName() + ", Size: " + font.getSize()));

    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:
`Montserrat Medium Italic, Size: 1`

note: replacing `font.getSize()` with `font.getSize2D` prints `1.0`.

New: Using decode:

I am now using this

```
Font test = Font.decode("Montserrat Medium Italic-ITALIC-20");
```

(fixed class not loading)

Update 2:

this line:
`Font mont = Font.createFont(Font.ITALIC, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/data/Montserrat-MediumItalic.ttf"));`

throws `IllegalArgumentException: font format not recognized`

Comment: Does `ge.registerFont(mont)` return `true`? Do you get any output if you try to list the font *before* registering it?

Comment: What `mont.getSize()` return?

Comment: @JohnBollinger this is (part of) the javadocs for getSize(): `Returns the point size of this <code>Font</code>, rounded to an integer.`

Comment: Also, register does return true. Putting the output before the register results in no output at all.

Comment: I can read the documentation of `Font.getSize()` for myself, thanks.  And did.  I asked about the result of a specific expression involving an invocation of that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the size is not actually being set (stuck at 1).

This seems unlikely to be the case.  I asked for direct confirmation in a comment on the question ("What `mont.getSize()` return?" -- oops, what embarrassingly bad grammar), but so far you have not answered.  I am reasonably confident that if you check, you will see that `mont.getSize()` evaluates to the size you requested.

An alternative explanation for your observed behavior is readily available.  You are using `GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()` to report on the registered fonts, but according to [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAllFonts()), this method

> Returns an array containing **a one-point size instance** of all fonts
>   available in this GraphicsEnvironment.

(Emphasis added.)

Another answer and especially comments on it suggest that the `Font` objects returned by `GraphicsEnvironment.getAllFonts()` might differ in other ways, too, from corresponding `Font` instances passed to `GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont()`.  Although such variations are not documented as far as I can see, they are consistent with the intended usage of `Font` objects obtained from a GE, as the `getAllFonts()` docs describe:

> Typical usage would be to allow a user to select a particular font. Then, the application can size the font and set various font attributes by calling the deriveFont method on the chosen instance.

They go on to say that

> If a font in this GraphicsEnvironment has multiple programmable variations, only one instance of that Font is returned in the array, and other variations must be derived by the application.

I'm not positive that "multiple programmable variations" means attributes that can be modified when you derive one `Font` object from another (for then what font *wouldn't* have programmable variations?), but it is clear that `getAllFonts()` is not a mechanism for reading back the exact `Font` objects previously presented to `GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont()`.  Those objects might not even be retained as such.

On the other hand, you can perhaps be relieved that you are not responsible for registering all the different font variations you may want in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am printing `mont.getSize()` right after `mont.deriveFont(20f)` and it is printing "1"

Comment: @PhaseRush, if the `getSize()` method of the `Font` instance obtained via a call to `deriveFont(20f)` returns 1, then something is badly wrong.  I can't help noticing, however, that your comment describes testing something different.  `mont.deriveFont(20f)` produces and returns a *new* `Font` instance; it does not modify the one on which it is invoked.  Thus `mont.getSize()` should return the same value afterward that it did immediately before.

Comment: @PhaseRush You are not printing `mont.getSize()` in the code in your question.

Comment: okay thanks I fixed my issue by doing 2 things.
1. updated size by changing Font mont = bunchOfFuncs(); mont.derive(20f); to Font mon = sameBunchOfFuncs().derive()
2. fixed IllegalArgEx by changing ttf file name to "Montserraft.ttf". Now when i need the font i use Font.decode(Montserrat-PLAIN-20) and it works

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is the problem. When you call `ge.registerFont(mont)`, it does exactly that, it registers the **underlying font**, without the modifications to the font object. The `deriveFont()` function only changes the state of the current font object, but cannot modify the actual font. When you register a font, it is registered with the size of 1. If you print the size of all the other fonts, you will find that they also have the default value of 1. I do not think that you can register a font with a custom default size, or override the default size of `Font.getFont()`. When you get a font by using `Font.getFont()`, it will always have the default size of 12 (from the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getFont-java.lang.String-)).

If you need to have a the font specially formatted, I would suggest creating a static class variable:

```java
Font MontMediumItalic_20;
```

Then load the font once, either in a resource loader, or the constructor, and apply all the modifications to it.

Alternatively, you can also use [`Font.decode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#decode-java.lang.String-)

Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: What "underlying font"?  The `Font` class has a concept of deriving one font from another, but no sense of one underlying another, and certainly it provides no means to obtain such an underlying font.  Moreover, `GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont()` documents that it can be used to register *only* created fonts, such as those obtained via `Font.deriveFont()`, which would not make sense if what it registers were really some sort of ancestral, original, underlying font.

Comment: On the other hand, it is plausible that a `GraphicsEnvironment` would register fonts at a standard size, such as 1 point, though the docs provide no reason to expect such behavior.

Comment: @Jhon by underlying don't, I meant the base font, as loaded directly from the .tff file, without any modifications except normalizing the font size to 1.

Comment: Again, the `Font` class has no sense of such a thing, nor does that seem consistent with the requirement that `Font`s registered with a `GraphicsEnvironment` be *created* ones.

Comment: @John I agree that `deriveFont` is counter intuitive But there is no point in registering a font with non standard size, because as per the specification, any call to `Font.decode` or `Font.getFont` will either return the specified size, or the standard size of 12.

Comment: I already said it's plausible that fonts get registered at a standard size, but again, that's not a documented behavior.  And that's certainly different from ignoring *other* font attribute modifications that may have been applied via the various `Font.deriveFont()` methods, which it seems would be implied by registering some form of original base font instead of the derived one presented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont-int-float-), `Font.deriveFont` can only change the style (bold, italic, normal, etc.), the size, or add one or more `AffineTransform`s. When `GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont` is called, it ignores **all** the modifications, and registers a font with size 1, style 0 (normal) and normal AffineTransform. I have tested this behaviour on my PC, running Windows 10 with Java 1.8.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow with the explanation, since to me it seems you imply `deriveFont` is useless, since it doesnt actually change anything. Regardless, I am having trouble with `decode`. See updated post for details.

Comment: @PhaseRush I am saying that calling `deriveFont` and then passing the `Font` object to the `GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont` function, or passing an unmodified `Font` object to `GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont` does not make a difference. You cannot register a font with custom size, style or affine transform.